# Logging the exit of a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging

So I wrote a tool with some batch commands, nothing specific. In the beginning the user can choose which task to perform thanks to a loop.

In that loop I included the "Q" option, as to quit the batch file. When this happens, it gets written to a logfile to check when the user started the script(s), and when it ended.

The issue is this only happens if the user actually quits/exits with Q. If (s)he quits by just closing the batch file, this won't be logged.

In short: how can I record when the user has quit the batch file without using the build-in function?

Comment: Unless some other process/batch file is monitoring it, you can't log the time it is terminated by a user clicking the close icon.

Comment: On second thought - You could have your batch file update the timestamp on a temp file regularly and the file will retain the date and time of the last time it was updated.  It would then normally require manual intervention to get the time/date - but that would give you an approximate time of when the batch file was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a batch file can't receive the "exiting"-event. What you can do is:

1. Make a *launcher.bat* file, that starts the original *(yourfilename).bat* file with:

   start /wait *(yourfilename).bat*
2. the *launcher.bat* file will now wait until you close the second *(yourfilename).bat* file. place your log-information on the next line of *launcher.bat*
3. convert *launcher.bat* to *launcher.exe* using [bat to exe converter](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e) (and make it **invisible**).

Comment: Yep, I know about that technique but wanted to avoid it. Thanks though!